# Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\GraceCancerFoundation.png'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send the uploaded files to mail. This is my asp.net code. I'm getting error

```
for (int x = 0; x < Request.Files.Count; x++)
{
    HttpPostedFile PostedFile = Request.Files[x];
    if (PostedFile != null && PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
        string FilePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(PostedFile.FileName);
        try
        {
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FilePath));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\GraceCancerFoundation.png'. Actual Path:
>   E:\GraceCancerFoundation.png

Answer (score 0):

You have received the file in the request, save it to disk then add it as an attachment.

Instead, you could just pass the stream to the attachment instead of the path

```cs
for (int x = 0; x < Request.Files.Count; x++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile PostedFile = Request.Files[x];
            if (PostedFile != null && PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(PostedFile.InputStream,  
                                                           PostedFile.FileName,
                                                           System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is showing The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.Mail.Attachment.Attachment(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: After downloading the uploaded file from mail. I didn't see any data, it is showing that we don't support this file format

Comment: No, Still i'm getting the same message that "It looks like we don't support this file format."